# Azure Functions -> Can not inject IServiceProvider or IFunctionsHostBuilder into factory class constructor

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

I am referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) link that explains how to implement DI in Azure functions.  I want to implement a `Factory` pattern where my `Factory class` should be able to resolve other dependencies while constructing the factory object.

Here is the code.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {

        System.Console.WriteLine("***************************I am in startup....");
        builder.Services.AddScoped<PayloadProcessorFactory>();
        
        /*  I tried to explicitly add IFunctionsHostBuilder to Services but its not working.
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IFunctionsHostBuilder>((s) =>{
            System.Console.WriteLine("test");                
            return builder;
        });*/

        /*No problem with below two dependencies and are getting injected without any issue*/
        builder.Services
        .AddScoped<IPayloadProcessor,DoctorPayloadProcessor>()
        .AddScoped<DoctorPayloadProcessor>();

        builder.Services
        .AddScoped<IPayloadProcessor,PatientPayloadProcessor>()
        .AddScoped<PatientPayloadProcessor>();
    }
}
```

Here is my factory class

```
public class PayloadProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IFunctionsHostBuilder builder;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public PayloadProcessorFactory(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder,ILogger<PayloadProcessorFactory> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
       this.builder = builder; //Builder is always null
       _logger.LogDebug("Constructing PayloadProcesorFactory");
    }
}
```

In the above code value of **builder** is always **null** hence I can't resolve dependencies using following statement

```
payloadProcessor = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
                .GetRequiredService<DoctorPayloadProcessor>();
```

In `Startup.cs` I tried to explicitly add `IFunctionsHostBuilder` to the `service collection` but after that, I ran into below issue.

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Configuration.ScriptHostOptionsSetup'.'
```

**QUESTION**
How can I inject `IServiceProvider` to my factory class in order to build a complex objects and resolve multiple dependencies?

**Project details**

- Dotnet framework - netcoreapp2.1
- Azure functions version : 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the factory patter with DI in .NET Core.
You don't need to inject the service provider to resolve the classes.

Sample factory interface

```
public interface IFactory
{
    IWorker Create(WorkerType workerType);
}
```

Sample factory implementation

```
public class Factory: IFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IWorker> _workers;

    public AuthenticationEngineFactory(IEnumerable<IWorker> workers)
    {
        _workers = workers;
    }

    public IWorker Create(WorkerType workerType)
    {
        var worker = _workers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.WorkerType == workerType);
        if (worker is null) throw new System.ArgumentException($"Worker with type '{workerType}' is not supported.");
        return worker;
    }
}
```

Sample worker interface

```
public interface IWorker
{
    WorkerType WorkerType { get; } // This can be an enum.
    void DoWork();
}
```

Sample worker implementations.

```
public class Worker1Implementation : IWorker
{
     public WorkerType WorkerType => WorkerType.WorkerType1;

     public void DoWork() {}; // Add implementation
}

public class Worker2Implementation : IWorker
{
     public WorkerType WorkerType => WorkerType.WorkerType2;

     public void DoWork() {}; // Add implementation
}
```

In your functions Startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFactory, Factory>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWorker, Worker1Implementation>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWorker, Worker2Implementation>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer to this question is still relevant, but I would approach this task the following way. I'd only register two implementations of *IPayloadProcessor* and a factory and then use the factory in a consumer of *IPayloadProcessor* (I named it *PayloadProcessorConsumer* in my example) to get the needed type based on some parameter (in my example I'm using a *string* but it could very well be a *bool* or an *enum*).

So in terms of your initial example it would look like:

*Startup.cs*

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped<PayloadProcessorFactory>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<DoctorPayloadProcessor>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<PatientPayloadProcessor>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<PayloadProcessorConsumer>();
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that you won't need to register *IServiceProvider* in the IoC container, it's there by default and it allows you to resolve the registered services in the factory itself.

*PayloadProcessorFactory.cs*

```
public class PayloadProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<PayloadProcessorFactory> _logger;

    public PayloadProcessorFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<PayloadProcessorFactory> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IPayloadProcessor Create(string processorName) // I'd use enum or bool here
    {
        if (processorName == "Doctor")
            return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DoctorPayloadProcessor>();
        else
            return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PatientPayloadProcessor>();
    }
}
```

Then in the class which should be consumer of a particular *IPayloadProcessor* the factory is injected and the required processor is instantiated at runtime.

*PayloadProcessorConsumer.cs*

```
public class PayloadProcessorConsumer
{
    private readonly PayloadProcessorFactory _payloadProcessorFactory;

    public PayloadProcessorConsumer(PayloadProcessorFactory payloadProcessorFactory)
    {
        _payloadProcessorFactory = payloadProcessorFactory;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var processorName = "Doctor"; // TODO some logic to retrieve required processor name from configuration

        IPayloadProcessor payloadProcessor = _payloadProcessorFactory.Create(processorName);

        // TODO: work to do with IPayloadProcessor
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm oversimplifying the example and avoiding introducing interface for the factory itself etc., but I believe it's enough to illustrate the idea.

There is also a pretty detailed [article in Microsoft Docs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/dependency-injection-on-azure-functions-5-ways-selecting/ba-p/1502394) on a topic which is close to this one.